# How to navigate within page in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

For my home page I have my route as `<Route exact path="/" ><Home /></Route>` and for my docs page I have my route as `<Route exact path="/docs" ><Home /></Route>`.
I wanted to navigate within  docs page and for that I did

```html
<a href="#id" >navigate</a>
```

And it works.
But when I do the same i.e.

```html
<a href="#about" >About</a>
```

for Home page it changes the url to `http://localhost:3000/#about`  but didnot naviagte to about section.

Answer (score 1):

Use the id, 'about' inside the header or any tag which you want to navigate. Eg:

```
 <section id='about'></section>
```

Comment: I do have `id="about "`  in  my page but it doesnot navigate to that section . But it work as expected in `/docs`  page.